# How to check in CODED UI if text field is a required field?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am new in coded UI, I just want to ask if there's any way to check if the text field in a web application is required?

HTML:
`<div class="col-sm-7">
           <input id="txt_title" type="text" name="Title" value="@Model.Asset.Title" class="form-control" required>
     </div>`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing this in two steps:

- Get the control based on its ID
- Ensure that the definition of the control contains "required"

Here's a code example:

```
HtmlTextArea requiredInput = new HtmlTextArea(browserWindow);
requiredInput.SearchProperties.Add("Id", "txt_title");
string controlDef = requiredInput.ControlDefinition;
Assert.IsTrue(controlDef.Contains("required"), "Test Failed: Input should be required");
```

Please mark as the answer if it accomplishes what you're saying. Thanks!